# striking through the text

Tags: iphone

I need to strike through the text of a multi-line label. Is there a way to do it?
Any suggestion would be greatly helpful. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

if you want do it with UILabel for iPhone you can't :(

so there are 3 ways:

1. (simplest) use UIWebView:

   ```
   // set html header with styles, you can certainly use some other attributes       
   NSString * htmlWrap =  @"<html><head><style>body{text-align:left; background-color:transparent; color:black; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:line-through; font-size:%dpt}`</style></head>`<body>%@</body`></html>";
   NSStrring * myText = @"My sample strikethrough text";
   webView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
   [webView setOpaque:NO];
   NSString * htmlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlWrap, 12, myText];
   [webView loadHTMLString:htmlText baseURL:nil];
   ```
2. use unicode combining diacritic (this works with any objects labels, textfields etc.)

   "long stroke overlay" (U+0336) or
   "combining low line" (U+0332) before
   each charecter in your string. Use

   ```
    -(void)getCharacters:(unichar *)buffer range:(NSRange)aRange
   ```

   to create unichar array from string (allocate double size of string length), then rearrange array and add  U+0336 or U+0332 before each character, then convert unichar array back to NSString with

   ```
    -(id)initWithCharacters:(const unichar *)characters length:(NSUInteger)length
   ```

   **but in most cases this looks bad**
3. Draw it manualy on context.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for a single line label.

```
@interface UILabelStrikeThrough : UILabel {
}
@end

@implementation UILabelStrikeThrough
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat black[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, black);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 2);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGFloat halfWayUp = (self.bounds.size.height - self.bounds.origin.y) / 2.0;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, self.bounds.origin.x, halfWayUp );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width, halfWayUp);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

Comment: but is drawrect called when we setText, i tried it using with setText, but didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Improved @RefuX code to handle location and width of the strikethrough.
I will add multiline support soon.

Multiple lines now supported

[Gist for UILabelStrikethrough](https://gist.github.com/1054706)

Comment: Apple doesn't support to change in any UI Control.... Its work fine but Apple reject the app if we use this code...

Comment: Why would apple reject? I've released an app with this code.